# Getting selected option index of select element

Tags: jquery

How can I get selected option index of `<SELECT>` with javascript. It is easy to get value with the help of jQuery's `val()` method but I couldnt get the index 0, 1, 2...

I can get it by some painful ways but I believe there must be something which can do it directly.

I create my select element on fly like this :

```
$formInput = $('<select class="userInput">');
$.each([A,B,C,D,E], function (i, v) {
    $option = $('<option value="' + v + '">' + v+ '</option>');
    $formInput.append($option);
});
```

And all methods I tried

`$formInput.prop("selectedIndex")`

`$formInput.get(0).selectedIndex`

`$formInput[0].selectedIndex`

did not work.

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QQrAR/36/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `selectedIndex` property of the DOM element:

```
$("#selectElement")[0].selectedIndex
```

using javascript

```
document.getElementById('selectElement').selectedIndex
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QQrAR/37/)**

Comment: Thank you but I guess I asked this question in wrong way. I edited my question. I created my select element on the fly and I think it changes something.  Could you please check it again

Comment: try `$(".userInput")[0].selectedIndex`

Comment: There are a lot of these objects and I have to reach their selectedIndex.I prefer reaching them while generating instead of selecting them after generation.

Comment: would be great if you can create the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

using [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

```
$("#selectElement option[selected]").index()
```